# Pausing deletion of directories if load is high

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, rm

I have a list of directories that I'd like to delete. However when I do them all at one, load spikes on the box. Does anyone have an example of a script that would wait until load was under a certain level before proceeding with the deletion (interation of the loop)

Answer (score 2):

Better still, use `ionice`.

```
ionice -c3 ./deletion-script
```

This'll cause your delete command only to run when the disk IO is free, so it has the lowest priority. [Cyberciti](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-set-io-scheduling-class-priority.html) has a nice little article on all the variants you have, and how to use them.

Comment: Tried it - still caused load to spike. Its a very busy box.

Comment: Do you have cPanel? cPanel has a binary called `cpuwatch` designed for exactly this, but I haven't stumbled across a free equivalent.

Comment: You should check `cpulimit` daemon (http://cpulimit.sourceforge.net)

Comment: It sometimes helps to use both "nice" and "ionice" on top of each other. Depends a bit of the exact flavor of Unix and the specifics of the system you are running, but if it works in your case it would be a quick and dirty easy solution.

Comment: @lik `cpuwatch` allows you to specify a load average values, which is a little different to `cpulimit` which is more about cpu time.

Comment: @Jay your are correct, `cpuwatch` tool is more appropriate in this case, but unfortunately it`s a part of paid product, so simple copy of `/usr/local/cpanel/bin/cpuwatch` binary executable may violate license.

Answer (score 2):

`ionice` is probably the best/simplest solution, but its only really delaying the inevitable and potentially just mean prolonged medium load versus a short run of high load.

There is a good write up here http://www.depesz.com/2010/04/04/how-to-remove-backups/ on a systematic controlled approach.

Changing the io scheduler, removing journals, atime and diratime are also contributory factors. There is also a different deletion binary `fastrm` , you can find the man here http://linux.die.net/man/1/fastrm

#### Don't try this at home

A while ago, we were testing faster deletion methods of deletion for terabytes of data. In the end it actually proved quicker to start a `rm` or `mv` then interrupt the process with `^c`. Then restart the machine with a forced `fsck` - which then would clean up the inodes and free up the subsequent space on the file system.

It worked surprisingly well and far quicker than a traditional delete - but I would never ever do it on a production system. Ever.

Comment: Note: `ionice` only works with the default [CFQ scheduler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CFQ).